is turf toe possible from misaligned cleats?
My big toes have been bothering me for a little while.  The strange thing is that they generally don't bother me when I'm biking, it is only when walking, running or anything involving flexing the big toes.
I haven't experienced this sort of discomfort before, this is new to me.
I went back to Shimano pedals about 3 months back and subsequently have been having toe pain.  Though, I didn't make any correlation because it was fairly mild, and I have been biking about the same mileage I have been for the past 10 years.  The discomfort is enough that when playing tennis, I move slowly as if I'm moving in slow motion just to avoid putting extra stress on my toes and when walking, I'm not longer the fastest, but the slowest.
I made a change about a month back to rotate the cleats such that my feet were more parallel with the frame instead of the toes pointing in.  I'm not sure why I had my toes pointing in, but they were.  At the same time, I stopped running and 2 weeks after that, I took a week off of cycling to see if there was any improvement.
After a week off from biking, my toes felt better with just the residual stiffness feeling.  I didn't really notice any improvement from not running.
I resumed cycling because it is hard for me to be inactive and my toes felt better than they used to even if they weren't 100%.
The first day was fine, the 2nd day, I went for about 20 miles (typically not that much for me) and afterwards, I noticed toe pain with my tennis shoes (prior to this injury, they didn't bother me, but they do have a narrower toe box), but not so much with my crocs.

should I take more time off from biking and wait till my toes feel 100%?
is it possible that the alignment of my cleats caused this issue?  I believe that is the only change I made around the same time.
has anyone experienced this sort of issue from biking and how long does it take to recover especially if I was doing it for an extended period of time?

EDIT #1

My shoes are Louis Garneau LS-100, yes, they are narrow, but I've never had pain there before, especially while biking and I generally don't have pain while biking, it is only when walking or running.
I am a toe down pedaler, but I noticed that I don't necessarily keep my feet flat, I sometimes allow the outside of my foot to roll down and then inside up, twisting the foot.
I am using road cleats with 6 degrees of float.  Even with that amount, I noticed that I was flexing the shoe because I had the cleats pointing my toes in (by mistake) and I later corrected that.
The soles are still stiff.  I was using Look Keo 2 Max up until 3 months ago (for nearly 2 years), the SPD-SL R-540 then, PD-R550L presently.  The Shimano pedals are nearly identical, I don't see those differences affecting my feet, the cleats are identical.
I presently moved the cleats all the way forward on my shoes and I still feel like the pedal spindle is behind the big toe.  When I first started with clip-in pedals (about 8+ years now), that is where I had them.  I had moved them all around and I am aware that I want the pedal spindle to be under the 1st and 5th metatarsil and have that marked on the outside of my shoe.  I have been averaging more than 5000 miles per year for about the past 8 years.  This year is close to 7000, about 700 more than last year.  But yeah, I might try moving them back as that should also take pressure off of the toes (I would think).
Both big toes hurt when bending (when walking, they bend).  I wear crocs around the house at home and my toes feel mostly okay in those, but I notice the discomfort more in my tennis shoes.  I've used that brand and model of shoe for the past 10 years (yes, new shoes, but I get the same one).  It is mostly a stiff feeling, but can be sharp depending on how much they bend or how quickly I move.


How big is the toe-box area of the shoe compared to other shoes you wear?   Remember your feet swell slightly with exercise, so I've found that tightening the "bridge" straps to push the foot backward in the shoe to be helpful.

Also, do you pedal with your sole horizontal or are you a toe-down peddler ?

Which cleats are you using? Road or MTB. If road, how much float does the cleat have. You might want to try the 6 degree float if you aren’t already using them.

What shoes do you wear when riding? How old are they?  Are the soles still stiff?  How tight are they?  If you go for a long ride - longer than usual - do you get any pain anywhere on your feet?  Your shoes could be breaking down and/or your feet actually getting a bit larger as your arches fall as you age.  (Ask me how I know...) And "shimano pedals"?  Which ones, exactly?  There are also a lot of details you left out: Is it both feet, or just one?  Where are the cleats on your shoes?  Are they forward under the toes, or back more toward the heel?  What exactly hurts on your toe(s)?
